# Cordova LocalNotification stops running app

Tags: android, cordova, localnotification

I try to create local notifications on Android with Cordova LocalNotification Plugin.

I have made everything from this [tutorial](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/10ca4abfa6cbe322d324c76f49de772b10d8f81e/README.md), but app stops running when I call function window.plugin.notification.local.add().

- Plugin connected (e.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.0dev "LocalNotification")
- Everything in the App works fine.
- There is no js-errors in consol.log();
- Everything made by tutorial.
- I use "cordova run android" for building and testing app on my device (Sony Experia Z1).
- App stops after click on "Device is Ready" block;

My code is here:

```
    <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received" onclick="window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });">Device is Ready</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

How to solve this problem or how to track why is it happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, they have some errors in 0.8 version.

All you need to repair:

- remove 0.8dev (not stable version)
- install 0.7.8 (last stable version)
- do not use UNSTABLE versions of plugins :)